# Sort selected column from array

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort selected column. I have generated array with random numbers. This is my code to print selected column for example I'm trying to select 1st row = min.

```
int column = 10,
 row = 10,
 min = 1 ,
 max = 9;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 1) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length;  j++) {
        arr[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*(max - min) + min);
        System.out.printf("%2d", arr [i][j]);
    }
}

for (int k = 0  ; k < column ; k++) {
            System.out.print(arr[min][k]);
}
```

I have tried doing something like this to sort:

```
for (int k = 0  ; k < column ; k++) {
    for (int j = k + 1  ; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[k][min] > arr[j][min]) {
            int[] temp = mas[k];
            arr[k] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            }}
            System.out.print(arr[min][k]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [Arrays#sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) method with a comparator like this (Java8+). Here are examples sorting a specific column in Ascending and Descending order. Only works with a Matrix where all array columns are of equal length as demonstrated:

**Ascending Order:**

```
int[][] myInt2DArray = {{2, 1, 4, 6},
                        {5, 3, 7, 1},
                        {1, 2, 3, 4},
                        {6, 9, 2, 8}};

// Sort in Ascending Order based on 4th column (column index 3):
int columnIndexToSort = 3;

// Sort the Array:
Arrays.sort(ary, (a, b) -> a[columnIndexToSort] - b[columnIndexToSort]);

// Display Array in Console:
for (int[] array : myInt2DArray) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output to Console Window (note the fourth data column):

```
[5, 3, 7, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 6]
[6, 9, 2, 8]
```

---

**Descending Order:**

```
// Sort in Descending Order based on 3rd column (column index 2):
columnIndexToSort = 2;

// Sort the Array:
Arrays.sort(ary, (a, b) -> b[columnIndexToSort] - a[columnIndexToSort]);

// Display Array in Console:
for (int[] array : myInt2DArray) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Output to Console Window (note the third data column):

```
[5, 3, 7, 1]
[2, 1, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 9, 2, 8]
```